# .htaccess изображений

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Делаю запрос:
http://example.com/test/1012235.jpg

Идет перенаправление к скрипту при помощи .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} test
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|png)$ watermark.php
```

На локальном сервере работает отлично! А вот на рабочем при обращении к изображению не срабатывает, открывает напрямую файл. Если написать путь к несуществующему файлу, тогда срабатывает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может быть в качестве основного HTTP-сервера на сервере установлен nginx, настроенный на выдачу статических файлов, и только в случае их отсутствия управление передаётся Apache, который и учитывает правила в .htaccess?

Comment: блин, скорее всего так и есть.

Comment: можно проверить, посмотрев на HTTP заголовки ответа сервера - обычно там есть заголовк `Server`, в котором, сюрприз, находится название сервера, отдавшего ответ на запрос